# How to manage sessions through UDP for an intermediate bridge server between multiple clients and a duty server?

Tags: linux, network-programming, udp

I need to make a bridge like the following figure. It is just an UDP server that receives packets from clients, forwards it to another server. The scenario will be well understood by the figure.

```
+--------+sendto()  recvfrom()+-----------+                    
| client |------------------->|           |                         +-------------+  
|        |        1           | bridge    |sendto()      recvfrom() |             |
|        |                    |           |------------------------>|    duty     |
|        |                    |           |           2             |   server    | 
|        |                    |           |recvfrom()      sendto() | processing  |   
|        |                    |           |<------------------------|             |
|        |recvfrom()  sendto()|           |            3            |             |
|        |<-------------------|           |                         +-------------+  
+--------+         4          +-----------+
```

Here the function for sending and receiving data are written along the side of the device.
Communication processes are identified by numbers 1,2,3 and 4, under the arrow signs. I tried to draw the figure in such a way that it can represent a timeline: from top to bottom.

Now come to the point. When I have only one client to manage, it is pretty easy task to do so. But let us assume the client number can be many. Suppose the clients are phones connected to internet using a dialer and the server is a SIP server running Asterisk/ Freeswitch or something like that. In such a scenario many clients can be present. I do not want to use the bridge server as a proxy server (running kamailio and rtpproxy)so that the communication can be efficient.

Asterisk or a SIP server can manage udp sessions I know. But how can the bridge. As udp maintains no sessions how can I complete the fourth step. How can I identify the reply of the duty server for a client? What type of software (of course light weight for efficiency, and I myself need to write it) should be written for handling the sessions. If anyone can give me an idea of session management through udp it will be very helpful for me. I searched a lot but did not find any suitable answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to maintain a data structure for the two connections (client and server). An UDP connection is determined by 4 parameters: IP & Port from both source and destination). The implementation depends on how deep you need to go, you may use threads or async socket handling, or even both.

Comment: You mentioned using threads...I guess you meant one thread for one client. Do I get the point?

Comment: Yes, and when I mentioned "both" I meant using x threads for n connections (x <= n). "Thread per connection" has the advantage of simplicity but a disadvantage of performance and scalability when discussing a large amount of connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm I used on a generic Proxy implementation for TCP/UDP traffic:

### Program modules:

One Connection Creator & Multiple Proxy Workers

They are implemented as self contained threads.

### Flow:

The Creator module is responsible to accept and handle new connections. It informs and passes the initial data to a worker that will handle from that point on all I/O for that connection, in parallel it will open a connection to the other side (can be done in the worker as well).

The worker will get a connection and be responsible for it during its life cycle.

### Some Technical points:

An UDP connection is determined by IP and PORT (SRC and DEST).

The Creator may wait for messages from all sources, while the worker may wait for messages from a specific source (by binding the UDP socket).

For performance, workers should fit the number of cores a system has and allow each to handle async sockets. In addition, if a worker handles several sockets, an algorithm needs to be placed to load balance between the workers when the Creator/Boss distributes new connections.

Comment: Thank u very much for your detailed answer. I will try to implement it and let u know how it behaves.